# CSS sticky position with nested elements

Tags: html, css, position, parent, sticky

As far as I know, sticky position sticks to it's container before getting out of frame.

My problem is that I have some nested containers and a sticky element inside those, and want it to stick to it's grandparent.

One could suggest that I would bubble up my inner sticky child, but the problem is that it must stay inside it's parent because the parent is a flexbox that contains two elements, and I want one of those elements to be sticky while allowing the other to be scrolled away on overflow.

An example html:

```
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div class="sticky">sticky child</div>
    <div class="non-sticky">non-sticky child</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the styling:

```
.inner-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

Let's say that `main-container` is scrollable and `inner-container` is being scrolled through it.

I know there is no clear solution being supported by css, the question is if there is any trick to handle it.

Comment: I absolutely agree there is lack of documentation on this property value. What exactly are the requirements to get sticky to work? Placing a sticky element inside a block element seems to break it (https://codepen.io/nathanch/pen/eXNwPV) but on MDN this use-case is not mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to do, but is this somewhere near what you need?

```css
.inner-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  justify-self: flex-start;
  background-color: green;
}

.non-sticky {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  flex-grow: 5;
  flex-shrink: 5;
}

.main-container {
  height: 140px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.inner-container {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div class="sticky">sticky child</div>
    <div class="non-sticky">non-sticky child</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, you changed the direction of my flexbox.
I wanted it to be side by side, but just on of them to be sticky

Comment: I've updated the code. If it's still not close to what you try to achieve, could you make it a bit more visible on what your wanted result should be.

Comment: Still not the case I'm trying to solve. I guess the solution is not that straightforward anyways.
As I've said before, the scrollable div is the `main-container`, so that the `inner-container` is the one being scrolled up and down.
In your example, just the non-sticky child is scrolling, while, for example, the background of the sticky child's column is static.
Wish you got me this time. I'm pretty sure the solution includes changing something with the architecture of the html or implementing the sticky ability with JS since sticky position doesn't natively support what I'm looking for.